# What does this formula mean in quad_mpi.c?

Tags: c, math, mpi

```
double f ( double x )
{
  double pi;
  double value;

  pi = 3.141592653589793;
  value = 50.0 / ( pi * ( 2500.0 * x * x + 1.0 ) );

  return value;
}
```

This part of code quad_mpi.c I don't know what the value is. I thought it was a formula for finding pi, but it already has pi. I'm trying to read all quad_mpi.c but it's so hard for me.
[quad_mpi.c](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/c_src/quad_mpi/quad_mpi.c)

Comment: I would guess the sole purpose of that function is to demonstrate how an integral of a random function is done using MPI. With `f` being that random function.

Comment: The function makes no particular sense.  It looks like `abs(1/x^2)`.

Comment: From the link you posted, the literal purpose of this function is to:  _"Purpose:    F evaluates the function"_.  But to be honest, this is one of the worst descriptions I can imagine.  My guess is that it is to provide a sample payload to test functionality of your parallel processing design.  i.e. a payload that is distributed, does something and returns a response from several locations in your distributed network of uPs

Comment: @ryyker thanks a lot. I will explain to my teacher like your ans

Comment: @alinsoar I think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted, the literal purpose of this function is to: "Purpose: F evaluates the function".

```
/******************************************************************************/

double f ( double x )

/******************************************************************************/
/*
  Purpose:

    F evaluates the function.
*/
{
  double pi;
  double value;

  pi = 3.141592653589793;
  value = 50.0 / ( pi * ( 2500.0 * x * x + 1.0 ) );

  return value;
}
```

IMO This is an example of a really weak comment block descriptions :)

It appears that it could be used to provide a sample payload ( [as described here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07734.pdf) ) with a known set of attributes (i.e. memory usage, run-time duration, etc) as part of an approach to benchmark or in some other way verify the functionality of your parallel processing design. i.e. a payload that is distributed, does something and returns a response from several locations in your distributed network of uPs